# MPU6050 over PCA9548 in Raspberry not created IIO

Tags: raspberry-pi, mpu6050

I'm have the rpi zero w

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103+ #1529 Tue Mar 8 12:19:18 GMT 2022 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I'm have the mux device pca9548, pwm pca9685a and mpu6050. My config(/boot/config.txt):

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=i2c-mux,pca9548,addr=0x70
dtoverlay=i2c-pwm-pca9685a
dtoverlay=mpu6050
```

But for mpu6050 IIO not present. My boot log

```
[   26.864201] i2c i2c-1: Added multiplexed i2c bus 11
[   26.922771] i2c i2c-1: Added multiplexed i2c bus 12
[   27.042447] i2c i2c-1: Added multiplexed i2c bus 13
[   27.043409] i2c i2c-1: Added multiplexed i2c bus 14
[   27.062607] i2c i2c-1: Added multiplexed i2c bus 15
[   27.206863] i2c i2c-1: Added multiplexed i2c bus 16
[   27.292344] i2c i2c-1: Added multiplexed i2c bus 17
[   27.296982] i2c i2c-1: Added multiplexed i2c bus 18
[   27.297033] pca954x 1-0070: registered 8 multiplexed busses for I2C switch pca9548
[   28.584207] inv-mpu6050-i2c 1-0068: mounting matrix not found: using identity...
[   28.584288] inv-mpu6050-i2c 1-0068: supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[   28.621504] inv-mpu6050-i2c 1-0068: supply vddio not found, using dummy regulator
[   28.814805] inv-mpu6050-i2c: probe of 1-0068 failed with error -121
```

If direct connect mpu6050 to the i2c IIO present
What I'm doing wrong?